# Java: Match-3 Game, Fill Algorithm Performance

Tags: java

I'm trying to code a game match-3 type, but I face a problem now with my algorithm to fill the board. I'm using the threadlocalrandom to generate a random number from 2 to 9, and after that I fill the board with that number. So here's the problem: some or most of the cases the board are fill without any match, which means the board are fill so randomly that the board have no moves.

Does anyone know a better way to fill the board with random numbers, or a better algorithm to fill the board?

If I wasn't clear enough to you or need some part of the algorithm, I can provide it here.

Edit: [Rules](http://gamasutra.com/blogs/JonathanBailey/20150227/237544/Match_Game_Mechanics.php)

I'm follow the user click form, which means user click when a match is up.

The code I'm using for fill:

```
for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) { 
        board[i][j] = rnumber.getRnumber();
    }
```

Comment: For each number, add it (at least) twice

Comment: Please include a link to the rules of the *match-3* type game and your code that fills the board.

Comment: Maybe 2 to 9 is too much different types of tiles for your board. Have you tried with less ?

Comment: Judging by the image of the site you posted the board there doesn't get filled randomly space by space but instead has (Tetris) shapes places in it with random colours (and probably filled any leftovers open spaces at the end)

Comment: @vincrichaud this is for university project, so this 2-9 must be in.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS so what you are saying i should create shapes first put in random spots in array and then fill the remaining spots with random? the thing is i need to have a 2-9 display numbers, and after that i can think about the shapes and gui!

Comment: Forgive me for not reading the rules, but one general approach for creating solvable puzzles is starting from a solved state and then `unsolving` it.

Comment: @JeromeReinländer what do you mean, can you give me a example?

Comment: @VanishDark Let's assume you have a game where you can click on a field with 3 neighbors of the same color, they will vanish, surrounding tiles will slide together to fill the gap and your goal ist to clear the whole field. You could start with an empty field, add 4 adjacent tiles of the same color, add another 4 (maybe even between your first 4), then another set and so on. Each state of the puzzle creation will have at least one solution (solving it in the inverse order of your creation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to somehow define an intern rule that will force the matches to occur more often.

***Using shapes***

As mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49916919/match-3-game-fill-algorithm?noredirect=1#comment86850779_49916919) you could for example first fill your board using shapes. And then complete the empty places by solo random numbers. Your algorithm will look like :

```
public void fillBoard(Board board) {
    // get a randomly picked shape from a defines set
    // for example { |  L  T  ■ }
    Shape shape = getRandomShape();

    // While there is enough free spaces in your board for this shape
    while(board.hasPlaceForShape(shape) {
        //Choose the number to fill this shape with
        int number = getRandomNumber();
        // find and fill the next free space in your board with your shape and numberin
        board.findAndFillNextFreeSpaceForShape(shape, number);
        //pick a new shape to continue
        shape = getRandomShape();
   }

   //fill the rest of your board with random number
   List<Tile> emptyTiles = board.getEmptyTiles();
   for(Tile t : emptyTiles) {
       t.setNumber(getRandomNumber);
   }
}
```

This should give something like :

First step the shape is | of 7 :

```
 7 |   |   |   | 

 7 |   |   |   |   

 7 |   |   |   |   

   |   |   |   |
```

Second step, the shape is T of 2 :

```
 7 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 

 7 |   | 2 |   |   

 7 |   |   |   |   

   |   |   |   |
```

Third step the shape is ■ of 6 :

```
 7 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 

 7 |   | 2 |   |   

 7 | 6 | 6 |   |   

   | 6 | 6 |   |
```

Fourth step the shape is | of 5 :

```
 7 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 

 7 |   | 2 | 5 |   

 7 | 6 | 6 | 5 |   

   | 6 | 6 | 5 |
```

Last step, complete randomly

```
 7 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 

 7 | 9 | 2 | 5 |   

 7 | 6 | 6 | 5 |   

 3 | 6 | 6 | 5 |
```

***Pick number from adjacent tiles***

You could define a rule that will force adjacent tiles to match. For example you first fill, by a full random, the border of your board and some specific tiles of your board. For example :

```
 x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x

 x |   |   |   |   |   |   | x

 x |   | x |   |   | x |   | x

 x |   |   |   |   |   |   | x

 x |   |   |   |   |   |   | x

 x |   | x |   |   | x |   | x

 x |   |   |   |   |   |   | x

 x | x | x | x | x | x | x | x
```

Then to fill the empty tiles, you do not pick the number totally randomly between 2 and 9. You pick it randomly between adjacent tiles numbers.

```
 2 |   | 4 

 6 | x |       -> x is picked randomly in { 2, 3, 4, 6, 9 }

 6 | 3 | 9
```

***Build it from a solution***

As mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49916919/java-match-3-game-fill-algorithm-performance/49920161#comment86855497_49916919), a lot of puzzle are first build solved, then mixed. In the case you are building a game where the gravity pull tiles down. You can fill your board by adding set of tiles at the bottom of the board until it is filled. Every time you add a set it will push already filled tiles up. Set should be matching so put for example sets containing between 3 and 5 tiles.

First step, it was picked randomly to add a set of number 4 with a size of 3 from the second column

```
   |   |   |   |   |   |   |  

   |   |   |   |   |   |   |  

   |   |   |   |   |   |   |  

   |   | 4 | 4 | 4 |   |   |
```

Second step, it was picked randomly to add a set of number 9 with a size of 4 from the third column

```
   |   |   |   |   |   |   |  

   |   |   |   |   |   |   |  

   |   |   | 4 | 4 |   |   |  

   |   | 4 | 9 | 9 | 9 | 9 |
```

thrid step, it was picked randomly to add a set of number 5 with a size of 3 from the fourth column

```
   |   |   |   |   |   |   |  

   |   |   |   | 4 |   |   |  

   |   |   | 4 | 9 | 9 | 9 |  

   |   | 4 | 9 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
```

Etc...

***Add the same number more often***

As mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49916919/java-match-3-game-fill-algorithm-performance/49920161#comment86849223_49916919), you could add your numbers many times so you increase the chances of matches. Since your doing a match-3 game, add every number at least 3 times.

```
//pick a random number
int number = getRandomNumber;
//pick 3 random free tiles
Tile[3] tiles = get3FreeTiles(board);
//fill these tiles
for(Tile t : tiles) {
    t.setNumber(number);
}
```

If your board number of tiles is not a multiple of 3, fill the one or two remaining tiles with totally random numbers.

The more you add the same number the bigger are the chance you create matches. So maybe add numbers 5 by 5 and not 3 by 3.

Comment: So when you talk about shapes, its like tretis shapes but with number? since the game doesn't have levels, do you think the solution could be applied?

Comment: @Vanishdark Yes like tetris shapes. You "just" have to create function that given a shape and a number set the right int in your array to fill your board with this shape. I've edited my answer to show what it should look like.

Comment: ok i think i understand the flow of that, ill give you a try. i the next days i will give the feedback or ask more about if i could go further! Thanks for your answers and thought's.

Comment: so a new question come up into to my mind now. So to do the shape i need to create methods for each shape right? but i dont know if i'm too tired right now or is just a dumb question but here he goes, do i need to create for each shape method a new array to control the direction of the numbers goes? like for a L shape i need to create a array where i assign the start position the direction? i dont know if i was clear on this dumb question!

Comment: @Vanishdark I think there's a lot of possible implementation. Do it like you want/think it

Comment: so i was kinda stop on this project because i run out of time the get into it. But my mind was blowing information(questions) to myself. What's the best form to fill the board? from those options ofc. So i think building from the shape ill be a good choise, but since the game "never end" which means, the board still being fill after a match, i feel that option is not the best one. Pick number from adjacent tiles was never in my options. So Build it from a solution and Add the same number more often are my last options. So for a game "never ends" witch score which one is the best?